# Bounded integral of absolute value of derivative squared

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Old qual question:

Let $f$ be a $C^1$ function on $[0,1]$ and assume
$$\int_0^1 |f'(s)|^2\,ds\leq A.$$
Show that, for all $x,y\in[0,1]$,
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq A^{1/2}|x-y|^{1/2}.$$

I really don't know where to go with this one. I'm guessing using the mean value theorem somewhere, but I don't know.

Comment: FTC and Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic idea is using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have 
$$ f(x) - f(y) = \int_y^x f'(\xi)\, d\xi $$
The triangle inequality gives, wlog $y<x$
$$ \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{f(x)-f(y)}\le \int_y^x \abs{f'(\xi)}\,d\xi$$
The Cauchy-Schwartz inequality applied for $\abs{f'}$ and $1$, gives 
$$ 
 \int_y^x \abs{f'(\xi)}\, d\xi\le \left(\int_y^x \abs{f'(\xi)}^2\, d\xi\right)^{1/2} \left(\int_y^x \abs{1}^2\,d\xi\right)^{1/2}
  \le A^{1/2}\abs{x-y}^{1/2} $$